# Android - wrong location of percent character in arabic language

Tags: android, android-custom-view, arabic

In a custom view, I need to draw a text "100%" for different locales.

For the Arabic language, it should look like this:

[image: Arabic 100%]

The main point is that the percent sign should go at the **end** of the numbers, **after** them.

I tried different combinations to get this text natively from the Java/Android:

 `NumberFormat.getPercentInstance().format(1)` -> `١٠٠٪`

 `String.format("%d%s", 100, DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance().getPercent())` -> `١٠٠٪`

 `String.format("%d%%", 100)` -> `١٠٠%`

 and so on

So the problem is that all options put this percent sign at the **start** of the string, not at the **end**.

But! When I invoke `TextView.setText("١٠٠%")` - the widget renders this fine, as `"%١٠٠"` (I believe there are some hidden transformations in a StaticLayout inside the TextView - based on the current locale/text context).

 When I call `canvas.drawText("١٠٠%", x, y, paint);` - canvas draws it as is, so the result is wrong:

[image: Wrong result]

**PS1.** Other experiments:

 `String.format("%d%% %s", 100, 'م')` -> `"١٠٠% م"` (correct)

 `String.format("%d%% %s", 100, 'م').substring(0, 5)` -> `"١٠٠% "` (incorrect!)

**PS2.** I cannot rely on an RTL/LTR basis - some RTL languages (like Hebrew) use western Arabic numbers (100%), so simply reverting an expression would be wrong as well.

**PS3.** The only way I see now is to check that `DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance().getPercent()` is Arabic percent symbol (char 1642) and to reverse an expression manually, but I don't like such approach at all and this would be as a last resort.

I'm out of further ideas, please help!

Comment: Just to confirm: your device is exhibiting this behavior while set to Arabic language? (As opposed to having the device set to English language but using Arabic letters.)

Comment: @BenP., yes, the locale is ar_EG on a device.

Answer (score 0):

As a potential workaround, perhaps you could define different string resources for percentages in different languages in your app.

```
res/
   values/
      strings.xml: <string name="percent_format">%1$d%%</string>
   values-ar/
      strings.xml: <string name="percent_format">%%%1$d</string>
```

Then you could write `getString(R.string.percent_format, 1)` and get `1%` in English and `%١٠٠` in Arabic.

Comment: I thought about that, but there are other languages that can use East Arabic numbers, and I don't want to specify each separate case.